# Migração com Caracteres Estranhos?

Tags: c#, firebird, visual-basic-6, ascii, unicode

Os dados são de um banco `Firebird` e mesmo abrindo com ferramentas oficiais os caracteres não vêm no "formato" `br`, por exemplo:

```
ÁGUA vem µGUA
PÃO  vem PÆO
```

Encontre um site que ao informar um caractere especial, por exemplo `µ` ele me retorna o valor do caractere em `decimal, octal, etc`:

> Site: [http://unicodelookup.com/#µ/1](http://unicodelookup.com/#%C2%B5/1)

No exemplo acima o site retorna o valor `decimal 181` para o caractere `µ`. Se utilizarmos o atalho `ALT+181` ele retorna `Á` que é exatamente a letra que este código representa no primeiro exemplo acima. Tentei utilizar `var characters = Encoding.ASCII.GetChars(new byte[] { 181 });` mas retonra `?` ao invés do `Á`.

Minha pergunta é:

Exite alguma função que simule o código gerado por `ALT+181` para retornar um caractere?

> Aceito resposta em c# ou vb6

Comment: Adicionei a tag firebird, porque me parece um problema que possa ser resolvido no próprio banco ou durante a conexão, não tenho certeza ainda.

Answer (score 0):

Você pode efetuar um `Backup` e um `Restore` do seu banco de dados utilizando os seguintes comandos do `Gbak` para correção de `UNICODE`.

```
-FIX_FSS_D(ATA)       fix malformed UNICODE_FSS
-FIX_FSS_M(ETADATA)   fix malformed UNICODE_FSS metadata
```

Segue um exemplo do comando de restore.

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Firebird\Firebird_2_5\bin\gbak.exe" -se service_mgr -c -v -user sysdba -password masterkey "d:\base de dados\teste.fbk" "d:\base de dados\teste.fdb"-fix_fss_m win1252 -FIX_FSS_D win1252
```

Para mais informações sobre os comandos acesse

> https://www.firebirdsql.org/pdfmanual/html/gbak-cmdline.html

Comment: @rubStackOverflow Se a resposta lhe foi útil, se puder marque-a como aceita `√`, assim quando outros usuários visualizarem sua questão verão que já tem uma resposta correta e aceita por você.